# Using package name "pdftools" and trying to open a password protected file results in crashing RStudio as well as R.app

Tags: r, pdf, crash

This is surprising as no one has ever posted any such problem. I use OSX and while using package "pdftools" I am trying to read a password protected pdf file like this.

```
text_fedel<-pdf_text(fedel,opw="AAOXCYXHY12")
```

This crashes RStudio and takes R.app into a frenzy (have to force quit from activity monitor).

I have taken the core dump but it is 900MB in size. What should I do now?

Comment: I also tried the function _pdf_text_ with **lapply** over several pdf files and the code passes successfully if there is no protected file. But even if one protected file is present the RStudio crashes!